# Сконевертировать весь массив $_POST

Tags: массивы, post, php

День добрый.
Начал изучать php, написал небольшой скрипт для отправки почтовой формы! Для отправки использую Ajax, форма работает, но при получении на почту сообщения кириллицей приходя кракозябрами! Нашел решение через, `iconv`! Но если добавлять какие-то поля, то не очень удобно каждый раз прописывать строук `iconv` для каждого поля! Можно ли как то сконевертировать весь массив `$_POST` а не конвертировать каждый его элемент?!

Спасибо!

<?php

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251');

$t_post = date('d.m.Y');
$name =  trim(substr(htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_name']),0,200));
$surename = trim(substr(htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_surename']),0,300));
$subject = trim(substr(htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_subject']),0,300));
$message = trim(substr(htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_message']),0,3000));

if($name == ''){
    die("имя не указано");
};

if($surename == ''){
   die("Тема не может быть пустой");
};

if ($subject == ''){
    die("Тема сообщения не может быть пустой");
};

if ($message == ''){
    die("Сообщение не может быть пустым");
};

$to = "******@mail.ru";
$from = "vasya@pupkin.com";

$name_p = iconv('UTF-8','WINDOWS-1251', $name);
$surename_p = iconv('UTF-8','WINDOWS-1251', $surename);
$subject_p = iconv('UTF-8','WINDOWS-1251', $subject);
$message_p = iconv('UTF-8','WINDOWS-1251', $message);
$messag_combine ="Имя отпрваителя: $name_p \r\nФамилия:$surename_p 
    \r\nТема: $subject_p \r\nTекст сообщения: $message_p \r\nВремя отправки формы: $t_post";

if(
mail($to,$subject_p,$messag_combine)
  )
{
  die("Сообщение отправленно");
};

die ("Какое-то дерьмо с отправкой");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете в вашей форме все поля называть как-то так:
**Form[user_name], Form[user_surname]** и тд. Выглядеть это должно примерно так:

```
<form>
<input type="text" value="" name="Form[user_name]" />
<input type="text" value="" name="Form[user_surname]" />
</form>
```

После этого в вашем php коде Вы можете получить массив Form и пройтись циклом (foreach например) по полям этого массива. Пример:

```
foreach($_POST['Form'] as $name => $value)
{
   $_POST['Form'][$name] = iconv('UTF-8','WINDOWS-1251', $value);
}
```

После такой манипуляции у вас все поля должны быть в нужной вам кодировке (не забудьте что поля лежат в массиве $_POST['Form']).

**НУ А САМЫЙ ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ВАРИАНТ ЭТО ВСЕ ЖЕ ПОМЕНЯТЬ КОДИРОВКУ В ФАЙЛЕ С ФОРМОЙ :)**

Comment: Сапсибо! Я пробовал менят кодировку в файле формы, это никак ни испрваило ситуацию! На mail ru все равно приходить в KOI-8, и отображается не правильно!

Comment: Еше попутный вопрос,  для того чтобы выполнить trim, htmlspecialchars и substr нужно пистаь отдельные foreach циклы?? или это можно все уместить в один ??
Вроде допер!
Вот так сделал  $_POST['Form'][$name] = iconv('UTF-8','WINDOWS-1251', htmlspecialchars(trim($value)));

Comment: У файла своя кодировка, у исполняемого кода своя кодировка, у выводимого кода своя кодировка ?

Comment: мне кажется можно вообще весь _POST и _GET фильтровать, а если есть теги сперва кодировать, а потом декодировать.